# Nginx service start failure in CentOS 5.5

Tags: nginx

I installed Nginx in centOS 5.5 using YUM from Nginx repo.

After installation, it is initially in service stopped status. I want to start Nginx service now and configure it to be started at boot time. Before starting the service, I created a new ssl configuration in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf

On the third line of this configuration file, I set server name as follow:

```
server_name   {{ www_name }};
```

I executed the following commands in terminal:

```
$ chkconfig nginx on
$ service nginx start
```

chkconfig command got executed successfully, but service start command gives me following error:

> Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] directive "server_name" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:3

This is how my ssl.conf looks like:

> server {
>       listen                     443 default_server;
>       server_name                {{ www_name }};
>       underscores_in_headers on;
>       ssl                      on;
>       ssl_certificate          cert.pem;
>       ssl_certificate_key      cert.key;
>       ...
>       }

[This link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) explains the solution, but I can't understand. Surprisingly, someone else used this ssl.conf file before on another CentOS, somewhere else and I did not change anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ www_name }}` is not a valid entry. You need to use a domain name string or regex. The link you provided shows valid examples.

Comment: You are right, it's completely invalid input. I fixed it. thanks